# Bolding Input Field Values

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I want to bold the value of an input field after it's been submitted. This is the result I get when I use .bold()

http://puu.sh/j4e35/b77ea3f62e.png

Why is it doing this and how can I bold it?

```
<body>
<h1 id="header">
    Socket.IO Chat
</h1>
<div id="message-box">
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
</div>
<div id="chat-box">
    <form action="" id="username-form" align="center">
        <input placeholder="Enter your nickname" autocomplete="off" id="nickname">
    </form>
    <form action="" id="client-input" align="center">
        <input placeholder="Press enter to send a message..." autocomplete="off" id="m">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
var socket = io();
var nickname;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#client-input').hide();
    $('#username-form').submit(function(){
        $('#nickname').hide();
        $('#client-input').show();
        return false;
    });
});

$('#client-input').submit(function(){
    if($('#m').val().trim().length == 0){
        null;
    }
    else{
        socket.emit('chat message',$('#nickname').val().bold() + ': ' + $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
    }
    return false;
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').prepend($('<li>').text(msg));
});

</script>
```

Comment: Just add this CSS rule: `#nickname{ font-weight: bold; }`. `.bold` [is not a standard method and does not automagically bold your text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold).

Answer (score 2):

The `.bold()` method does not actually make text bold, it merely puts `<b>` tags around the given string. Inside an input field, you will actually see these tags around the string because it is preformatted.

Instead use JavaScript to change the CSS of the input field to display its contents in bold:

```
$('#nickname').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<li>').text(msg)
```

Creates a `li` element and sets its text content. You want to set the html content.

```
$('<li>').html(msg)
```

However that would be pretty dangerous (xss injections). Instead you should send both the name and the message as an array or object to the server:

```
socket.emit('chat message', [$('#nickname').val(), $('#m').val()]);
...

socket.on('chat message', function(data){
    var line = $('<li>');
    $('<b>').text(data[0]).appendTo(line); //name
    $('<span>').text(data[1]).appendTo(line);//msg
    $('#messages').prepend(line);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with CSS, it's actually a lot easier than you are making it. You can insert the CSS right into the form element but I actually recommend using an external style sheet and connecting that with an ID.

```
#elementID {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

People don't seem to realize that you can use CSS styles on form elements just like any other element, inserting the code right within the PHP or JavaScript has the potential to create problems, at least from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with adding the font-weight: bold; inside of the #nickname object in the CSS portion is that it bolds the text inside the input field and not what the client submits in the input field. It looks like this

http://puu.sh/j4o2I/3560618f4b.png